# BERT model conversion from DeepPavlov to HuggingFace format

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface, deeppavlov

I have a folder with the ruBERT model, which was fine-tuned with the application of the Deeppavlov library.

The folder contains the following model files:

[image]

How do I convert it to Huggingface format so that I can load it this way?

```
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification

model_name = "folder_with_ruBERT"
auto_model_rubert = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, do_lower_case = False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to convert the tf checkpoints into huggingface format. The DeepPavlov's pretrained language models are already available as huggingface models.

https://huggingface.co/DeepPavlov

Comment: It's clear, but how do I load the weights of my finely tuned model, and not the original ruBERT model?

Comment: @senek you can either fine-tune your model with the newest version of DeepPavlov that's based on huggingface AutoModel, or alternatively you can convert tf checkpoint by using huggingface [script](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/converting_tensorflow_models#bert).

Comment: It worked, thank you. 

However, there is a warning 

Some weights or buffers of the TF 2.0 model TFBertForSequenceClassification were not initialized from the PyTorch model and are newly initialized: ['classifier.weight', 'classifier.bias']

but this is the topic of another question